# Python - file name adjustments

Tags: python, linux, file, rename

I have a number of csv files (6) in a Linux folder that I need to rename and relocate to a new folder on the same server.

<entity_name>_yyyymmdd_hhmmss.csv - bearing in mind the <entity_name> is a string that varies from file to file.

I need to be able to keep the original <entity_name> but replace the yyyymmdd_hhmmss with to day's date in the format yyyymmdd, so what we end up with is <entity_name>_yyyymmdd.csv

if this could be done using Python thanks.

Being new to Python the Internet was awash with ideas, some were close, but none seemed to help me achieve what I am after.

I have successfully manged to loop through the folder I need and read each file name, but am stuck renaming the files.

Comment: Why do this with Python when there are nice command-line tools for it? If this is just an exercise in using Python, you'll only learn by trying to do it yourself. I suggest you start with the `glob.glob()` function.

Comment: You can use `str.replace()` and `date.strftime()` to replace `yyyymmdd_hhmmss` with the date.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but we have a need to run this as a CRON task, so yes there is a element of learning, but an element of necessity as well.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you can't do it with the `rename` command instead of Python.

Comment: Is `yyyymmdd_hhmmss` literal, or a pattern for the old filename containing a date and time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just straight-line coding.  For each file, extract the base, add the date and extension, and rename.

```
import os
import glob
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
newpath = "wherever/we/go/"
for name in glob.glob('*.csv'):
    base = name.split('_',1)[0]
    newname = f'{base}_{today}.csv'
    os.rename( name, newpath+newname )
```

Comment: Your use of `split()`  won't work if the entity name contains `_`.

Comment: He also said that he needs to move to a new folder.

Comment: Re: split, that's true, but the spec didn't cover that.  `.split('_')[:-2]` could also work, but I'm betting they will accidentally run this on a folder where the conversion has already been done, and that would fail, because the new name doesn't have a time.  As we so often say, "this is not a contract coding service."

Comment: Why not just `.replace('yyyymmdd_hhmmss', today)`

Comment: as this will be an ongoing situation the yyyymmdd_hhmmss will change, so unless you can identify this at run time I cannot see it working.
Luckily <entity> never has an underscore so I may give that option a try,

Comment: Thank you everyone very happy with the outcome. Kudos to Mr Tim Roberts.

I learned a lot from this exercise.

Comment: @Barmar -- The old names did not have the literal string "yyymmdd_hhmmss".  They had some other date/time.  Yes, I was reading between the lines.